# Spring Boot 3.0 with Jpa 3.1 instantiation in query not working

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-kotlin

Since the upgrade to Spring Boot 3.0 following query is not working anymore:

```kotlin
   @Query("""
        select new com.example.OrderProductWithAmount(
            op, sum(op.amount), sum(op.paidAmount)
        )
        from OrderProduct op
        join op.order o join op.product p join o.table t
        where t.id = :tableId group by p.id
        """)
    fun getAllSummarizedByTableId(@Param("tableId") tableId: Long): List<OrderProductWithAmount>
```

```kotlin
data class OrderProductWithAmount(
    val orderProduct: OrderProduct,
    val amount: Int,
    val paidAmount: Int
) {
    constructor(
        orderProduct: OrderProduct,
        amount: Long,
        paidAmount: Long
    ) : this(
        orderProduct,
        amount.toInt(),
        paidAmount.toInt()
    )
}

@Entity
@jakarta.persistence.Table(name = "order_product")
data class OrderProduct(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long = -1,

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
    var order: Order,

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", nullable = false)
    var product: Product,

    @Column(name = "amount", nullable = false)
    var amount: Int,

    @Column(name = "paid_amount", nullable = false)
    var paidAmount: Int = 0,
)
```

Log:

```
Error performing dynamic instantiation : com.example.OrderProductWithAmount
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error performing dynamic instantiation : com.example.OrderProductWithAmount
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.sql.internal.InstantiationException: Error performing dynamic instantiation : com.example.OrderProductWithAmount
    at app//org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.instantiation.internal.DynamicInstantiationAssemblerConstructorImpl.assemble(DynamicInstantiationAssemblerConstructorImpl.java:58)
    at app//org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.readRow(StandardRowReader.java:104)
    at app//org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:198)
    at app//org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33)
    at app//org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:443)
    at app//org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:166)
    at app//org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:91)
    at app//org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31)
    at app//org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.lambda$new$0(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:113)
    at app//org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:335)
    at app//org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:276)
    at app//org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:571)
    at app//org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:363)
    at app//org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.list(QuerySqmImpl.java:1073)
    at app//org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:94)
    at java.base@17.0.5/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.5/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.5/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.5/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at app//org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:401)
    at app/jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy231.getResultList(Unknown Source)
    at app//org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:127)
    at app//org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90)
    at app//org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:148)
    at app//org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
    at app//org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136)
    at app//org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120)
    at app//org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164)
    at app//org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at app//org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at app//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at app//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at app//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at app//org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 104 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.instantiation.internal.DynamicInstantiationAssemblerConstructorImpl.assemble(DynamicInstantiationAssemblerConstructorImpl.java:52)
    ... 140 more
```

Is it not possible anymore to pass whole DB objects like I do it with `op`?

Comment: Can you provide more error information? Guess that one of your sum results is null and cannot be instantiated

Comment: @Jilliss I added more logs, but I cant see anything useful there.

Comment: The key is argument type mismatch   Try to modify to `select new com. Example. OrderProductWithAmount (sum (op) amount), sum (op. PaidAmount))`  And modify the constructor

Comment: @Jilliss That was my assumption yes, but then I am not able to pass the op itself to the constructor right?

Comment: Please add the `OrderProduct` class, also I believe the sum returns a double/float instead of a long (or it might even be a `BigDecimal` nowadays).

Comment: @M.Deinum Done. I think so too - but I don't know which type it is.

Comment: Looking at the specs it will return an `Long` according to the Spec. I suspect it tries to use the `Int` constructor for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `SUM` returns `Long` when applied to state fields of integral types (other than `BigInteger`); `Double` when applied to state fields of floating point types; `BigInteger` when applied to state fields of type `BigInteger`; and `BigDecimal` when applied to state fields of type `BigDecimal`.

This is from the [JPA 3.1 specification](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.1/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.1.pdf).

So it should return a `Long`. I suspect it gets confused by the constructors in your data class. What happens if you change the types from `Int` to `Long` and remove the additional constructor?

Comment: Actually this is working. I just wonder why this is not possible anymore in JPA 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

What looks like a problem with your sql try to change to the following

Since the upgrade to Spring Boot 3.0 following query is not working anymore:

```
  @Query("""
        select new com.example.OrderProductWithAmount(
            op, sum(op.amount), sum(op.paidAmount)
        )
        from OrderProduct op
        where op.id = :tableId group by op.id
        """)
```

I don't see that you have a t table and p table associated query
@kaulex

Comment: I updated the question, I forgot one line to copy with the join statements.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have created a constructor with the three default parameters (parameters used in JPQL query) and set all numeric field to Long.